# Recovering tree structure from pairwise distances

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Given some tree, one can create a set of lengths of shortest paths and their multiplicities.

For example, the tree $P_4$ has one shortest path of length 3, two shortest paths of length 2, and three shortest paths of length 1. The corresponding set would then be $D_{P_4} = \{(1,3), (2,2), (3,1)\}$. Thus, if $(a, b) \in D_T$, then there are exactly $a$ pairs of vertices $\{u, v\}$ such that $\mathrm{dist}(u,v) = b$ in tree $T$.

We need to account for ${n \choose 2}$ paths for a tree with $n$ vertices.

My question has to do with reconstructing the tree. That is, given such a set as above (and given that the set was indeed derived from a tree), can we uniquely reconstruct the tree it comes from?

Comment: Conventionally [path](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphPath.html) is a subgraph, not a number.

Comment: @Smylic Thanks for the comment! I've clarified it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randić had conjecture, that even more strong property of equality of distance degree sequences implies isomorphism of trees. But there are [counterexamples to Randić's conjecture](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190060111/abstract), one of them is below.

[image]

Both trees have the same *distance degree sequence* that is essentially the same as multiset
$$\{\,\{\,d(v, u) \quad \forall u\in V(G)\,\} \quad \forall v \in V(G)\,\}$$
of multisets of distances $d(v, u)$ from each vertex $v$ to all other vertices.

P. S.
It is easy to check that in your notation we have $D_{T_1} = D_{T_2} = \{\,(16, 5), (42, 4), (48, 3), (30, 2), (17, 1)\,\}$ for trees $T_1$ and $T_2$ above.